# Поиск по нескольким словам в django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Как реализовать поиск по нескольким словам на django? Пока ищет только при вводе одного слова в поисковой строке?

```py
def search(request):
    text = request.GET.get('search')

    if text:
        items = Item.objects.filter(name__iregex=text).select_related('from_category')
        paginator = Paginator(items,10  )
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    else:
        page_obj = Item.objects.none()
    return render(request, 'webapp/search.html', {'page_obj': page_obj, 'text': text})
```

Как сделать так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть текстом, а не скриншотом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/trie-data-structure-implementation-in-python/